# role of command interpreter in operating systems

Tags: windows, operating-system

I am reading about operating systems. I read that when the OS starts, a command interpreter is started as a user process and that when you click in a GUI element, e.g. the desktop symbol of an application, the command to start that application is passed to this command interpreter.

I know command interpreters in the forms of shell or cmd.exe. So does this mean that on Windows when I double click on a desktop icon for, say, word, there is a command interpreter underneath that processes this command? So clicking on the GUI elements equals writing a command in cmd.exe?

And under Windows, what is the name of that process as shown in process explorer?

Comment: Yes, every action which you perform is served by the command interpreter before being served by the OS; terminals/command prompt are a way which helps us type commands for the interpreter(e.g. bourne shell,bash shell).

Comment: Note that the icon you click is _not_ the application or a magic button. It is a shortcut to some file which may hold anything that has to be interpreted. What can interpret things? Right! Typically more complex programs are launched by the help of some setup script.

Comment: @arkascha: it is unusual in Windows for an application to launch via a script.  (Not unheard of, but unusual.)  Typically the shortcut points directly to an executable file, or to information in the registry that identifies an executable file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally, at least, the phrase "command interpreter" means only command-line interpreters such as `cmd.exe` and if you interpret the phrase that way, the claim is false.  When the interface is graphical, such as in Windows, we usually call it a "shell" instead.

The Windows shell is called Explorer, `explorer.exe` in Task Manager.

> So clicking on the GUI elements equals writing a command in cmd.exe?

They are equivalent, in the sense that they both serve broadly the same function (allowing the user to interface with the operating system) but not identical.

In particular, note that Explorer doesn't work by passing commands to `cmd.exe` or vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

In linux,Command interpreter takes the command from user and then gives this command to kernel.Command interpreter is also known as shell in linux.There are different shells available in Linux like bash,korn etc...I have implemented simple c base shell as shown  below,

```
/*header*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/*macros*/

/*maximum lenth of the line*/
#define LINE_MAX 10

/*function prototype*/
int getline1(char s[],int lim);

/*main*/
int main()
{
    char line[LINE_MAX];/*to store line*/
    int len;/*lenth of the input line*/

    /*clear the terminal*/
    system("clear");

    printf("************This is the C shell**********\n");
    printf("Enter ctrl+D to exit\n");

    /*calls the getline function to get input line*/
    while ((len = getline1(line, LINE_MAX)) > 0){

                /*if specified command is entered then execute it
         *else print command is not found 
         */
        if(!strcmp(line,"ls"))
            system("ls");

        else if(!strcmp(line,"pwd"))
            system("pwd");

        else if(!strcmp(line,"ifconfig"))
            system("ifconfig");

        else
            printf("Command is not found\n");
    }

    printf("Exiting from shell..\n");
    return(0);
}

/**
 * @brief getline1 gets the line from user
 * param [in] : s is string to store line
 * param [in] : lim is maximum lenth of the line
 *
 * @return 0 fail nonzero otherwise
 */
int getline1(char s[],int lim)
{
    /*c is to store the character and lenth is lenth of line*/
    int c, lenth;

    /*take the characters until EOF or new line is reached*/
    for (lenth = 0; lenth < lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n' ; ++lenth)
            s[lenth] = c;

    /*count the new line character*/
    if(s[0] == '\n')
        lenth++;

    /*assign null at end*/
    s[lenth] = '\0';

    /*return lenth of the line*/
    return lenth;

}
```